# MongoDB use $in 2 times in a single request

Tags: php, mongodb, operators

Is it possible to do two or more `$in` in one request ?

My code :
`find({_id: { $in: [ObjectId("5e96c5b11000ae32d0742d94")] } })`

Here I want to do another `$in` to filter my MongoDB.

(I can show you the structure of my base if anyone want it)

Hopefully it's clear.

Here is the result of a `find()` (here is only 6 adress I have a lot more but we don't care) :

```
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#5604 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(2) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#5630 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5e96c5b11000ae32d0742d94" } [0]=> string(5104518) "
{"id":"05009","type":"municipality","name":"Aspres-lès-Corps","postcode":["05800"],"citycode":"05009","lon":6.0005,"lat":44.8118,"x":937174.73,"y":6417022.74,"population":107,"city":"Aspres-lès-Corps","context":"05, Hautes-Alpes, Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur","importance":0.18009340385621533}
{"id":"05024","type":"municipality","name":"Valdoule","postcode":["05150"],"citycode":"05024","lon":5.5233,"lat":44.4615,"x":900711.69,"y":6376812.41,"population":212,"city":"Valdoule","context":"05, Hautes-Alpes, Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur","importance":0.21360128697297767} 
{"id":"05031","type":"municipality","name":"Champcella","postcode":["05310"],"citycode":"05031","lon":6.5242,"lat":44.7193,"x":979003.59,"y":6408468.91,"population":185,"city":"Champcella","context":"05, Hautes-Alpes, Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur","importance":0.20689148370809196} 
{"id":"05032","type":"municipality","name":"Champoléon","postcode":["05260"],"citycode":"05032","lon":6.2619,"lat":44.7429,"x":958141.88,"y":6410195.7,"population":144,"city":"Champoléon","context":"05, Hautes-Alpes, Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur","importance":0.19459101490553132} 
{"id":"05033","type":"municipality","name":"Chanousse","postcode":["05700"],"citycode":"05033","lon":5.6606,"lat":44.3633,"x":911996.46,"y":6366268.17,"population":40,"city":"Chanousse","context":"05, Hautes-Alpes, Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur","importance":0.13312939135127264} 
{"id":"05035","type":"municipality","name":"Châteauneuf-d'Oze","postcode":["05400"],"citycode":"05035","lon":5.8979,"lat":44.5038,"x":930323.7,"y":6382530.99,"population":28,"city":"Châteauneuf-d'Oze","context":"05, Hautes-Alpes, Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur","importance":0.11676874579085184}
```

And here is where I am taking the file :
https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/data/ban/adresses/latest/addok/adresses-addok-05.ndjson.gz

I import data via a controller in php :

```
$connection = new MongoClient();
        $db = $connection->france;
        $collection = $db->adress05;
        $collection->insert($jsonarray);
```

And I am converting it like this :

```
        $ndjsongz=file_get_contents('https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/data/ban/adresses/latest/addok/adresses-addok-05.ndjson.gz');

        $ndjson=gzdecode($ndjsongz);

        $bsonarray=explode("}",$ndjson, true);

        $json = MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($bsonarray));

        $jsonarray = json_decode($json);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `$in` several times per field. Also, if you add `$and / or` conditions, you can also use `$in` operator for the same field several times (depends on `$and / $or`).

Comment: Ok thank you, but where can I find the right syntax ? I didn't see anything about that on their website

Comment: Take look [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) docs

Comment: Yes thanks but i didn't see anything on the syntax of a double $in..

Comment: Try here https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: Ok it works, I don't understand the syntax of my DB, it's like all data are only under 1 ObjectId and I don't know how can I "naviguate" trought it.

Comment: May be I don't upload right the file... is this normal to have this : 
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#5604 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(2) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#5630 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5e96c5b11000ae32d0742d94" } [0]=> string(5104518) 

At top of my Database (when I do a find() ) ?

Comment: Can you post it into your question?

Comment: I just did it.
There is only 6 adress (I have more) but it change nothing.
I showed you the result of my find().

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your data? Do you Robo3t or other GUI to view your data?

Comment: Hmm I am not using GUI,  I tried NoSQLBooster but it cannot connect to my url..
I check my data only with a find() and I make my test via the mongo terminal.

Comment: I can show you the url where I take the file (it is <name_of_file>.ndjson.gz format)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax for an `$and` with multiple `$in` statements

```
find({
  $and: [{
    _id: {
      $in: [ObjectId('99500b4eb8ee4c8c6f129d86'),...]
    }
  }, {
    _id: {
      $in:[ObjectId('b81f234213f87fd0bc1ddd97'),...]
    }
  }
]})
```

Comment: And can I do a ```$in``` in a ```$in``` ?
I want to search a specific field in the field ```_id``` (ObjectId).

Comment: Ah, I think you've misunderstood what `$in` does, it's used to get docs where the given key's value is in a set of values. Eg I have a collection like `Docs = [{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}, {key: 'c'}]` I can query it like `Docs.find({key:{$in:['a','b']}})` which will return `[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]`.

Comment: Hmm ok, is their a possibility to do what I want ?

Because all my data are in only one "ObjectID"..

Comment: Oh, this will probably just insert one document which is actually all the documents in that ndjson. Can you please verify this for me by doing a `count` on the collection?

Comment: It return " 1 "

Comment: Yeah, insert is a command used to make one document (like one row in a relation db). I recommend connecting to your mongo via command line and using `mongoimport`. Documentation here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

Comment: Ok thank you, so my "$jsonarray" is good ? I need to "mongoimport" it and not "insert" thats it ?

Comment: don't worry about making a json array, you can just mongo import the data as is

Comment: I don't understand how can I make a 'mongoimport' on an url, I can do it for a file (--file) but not an url :/
Am I obliged to download files import it and delete it ?

Comment: AFAIK this is the case, I don't think this command supports the asynchronicity required to  fetch a file then import it, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.